# How to use locale for strftime in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, locale, strftime

I am using BigQuery to output a formatted Timestamp value using STRFTIME_UTC_USEC function, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#strftime_utc_usec) leads me strftime C++ reference,
which specify modifiers like %b (for month) etc. which are locale specific, 
is their a way to use locale specific month names using STRFTIME?

The only other alternative I see is to write my own UDF function and do a lookup using Map.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `STRFTIME_UTC_USEC` function is based on C++'s `strftime` there is no provision to supply locale. 
We usually recommend using Standard SQL which has [`FORMAT_TIMESTAMP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_timestamp) function, but it does not allow changing locale either.
You probably don't have to write complex UDF, just a simple `REPLACE` or `REGEXP_REPLACE` can be enough. Or you can have an array with localized month names - `["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", ...]` and get element out of it based on month `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)`